# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core

Tags: android, maven, opencv, gradle, javacv

I'm trying to use javacv library in my project.Hierarchy of libs folder

```
libs
-armeabi.jar
 -lib.armeabi
  -libjniopencv_core.so (and other .so files)
-javacv.jar
 -com.googlecode.javacv
  -cpp
   -opencv_core(class)
```

But when i try to create a yuiplimage on surfaceview created

`(yuvIplimage = IplImage.create(w, h, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1) )`

it gives this error

```
18378-18378/triptam.gofive.likaz E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core
            at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:340)
            at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:319)
            at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$CvArr.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:163)
            at triptam.gofive.likazz.MainActivity$CameraView.surfaceChanged(MainActivity.java:1394)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:628)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:88)
            at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:183)
            at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:695)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2123)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4872)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5410)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
            at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:338)
            at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:319)
            at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$CvArr.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:163)
            at triptam.gofive.likazz.MainActivity$CameraView.surfaceChanged(MainActivity.java:1394)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:628)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:88)
            at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:183)
            at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:695)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2123)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4872)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5410)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load jniopencv_core from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/triptam.gofive.likaz-1.apk", zip file "/data/data/triptam.gofive.likaz/code_cache/secondary-dexes/triptam.gofive.likaz-1.apk.classes2.zip"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/triptam.gofive.likaz-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:514)
            at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:448)
            at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:372)
            at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:319)
            at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:136)
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
            at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:338)
            at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:319)
            at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$CvArr.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:163)
            at triptam.gofive.likazz.MainActivity$CameraView.surfaceChanged(MainActivity.java:1394)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:628)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:88)
            at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:183)
            at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:695)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2123)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4872)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5410)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm new to native libraries and this worked fine before.Thanks in advance

Comment: I think your project lost references to the library, if you already had it installed before.

Comment: I kind of think thats the issue but please can you tell me how to overcome this?

Comment: It doesn't find the class of the library, so, try to install it again. And come back to compile the project.

Comment: Thanx victor that worked..

Comment: Hi victor sorry i had a restored version of my project on bitbucket and i compiled it and that worked before but now after making some changes in other parts of the code its again giving me the same error.Can you please tell me how to install those libraries again?

Comment: You need to try to install/add the library again. What type of library is? Jar file? Maven repo? Gradle dependency?